# Jetty Performance

Tags: kotlin, jetty-9

I've recently inherited a project written in Kotlin and extends Jetty 9.

This project is a proxy to our company's current production custom web-server written in C sharp.

In the process of testing the impact this proxy has on the performance of a simple hello world web-service call to the server I've seen the response time quadruple compared to calling the service directly through the web-server.

The choice to use Jetty and Kotlin was made before I joined the company and the original developer is no longer with the company so I can't answer any questions on why this was done this way. I've also not worked with either Kotlin or Jetty before.

So, does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the performance of the proxy - server interaction?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a JVM profiler such as [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) or [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html) to measure where exactly the bottlenecks are. Sometimes little problems cause major performance headaches. Given you profile the actual installation that causes problems, you'll also see memory usage. Not enough memory can cause blocking Garbage Collections.

Comment: Just one more hint: You can also enable [Garbage Collection logs](https://dzone.com/articles/enabling-and-analysing-the-garbage-collection-log) in your productive application to analyze memory. Those logs can be verify tedious to read, I would recommend to use a tool such as [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer) to analyze them.

Hopefully I able to point you to some ideas. Would you mind accepting the answer if you are happy with it?

Comment: Michael,  JProfiler was very helpful and identified a couple of areas that needed improvement. Thank you! I don't know how to accept your answer though.

Comment: Good to hear! Here is how accepting answers works: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work